# Harm the RAM via write-back (clflush)

Tags: x86, masm, ram

I wrote this x86 assembly code for the MASM:

```
loop_start:
mov dword ptr [esp], 0
clflush dword ptr [esp]
mov dword ptr [esp], 0FFFFFFFFh
clflush dword ptr [esp]
jmp loop_start
```

It writes in endless loop zeros and ones to the same address in memory.
In this example just the top of the stack.
The clflush instruction then forces the write-back from cpu-cache to the memory.
The question is, if this runs a day or so, would it harm the memory in time.
Because i know RAMs become errors in time, and for example ssd drives are limited writable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Flash (used in SSDs), DRAM has essentially unlimited write endurance.  It won't "wear out" from reads/writes much if any faster than just sitting there powered on.

BTW, `movnti` or `movntps` would be an easier way to do cache-bypassing stores.  Write a pair of cache lines alternating.

Comment: Oh I think I misunderstood the question completely. BTW, DRAM's write endurance is about [10^16 writes](http://terpconnect.umd.edu/~blj/papers/hpca2013.pdf). So if we assume a write takes 0.25 nanoseconds, it would theoretically take about 29 days to make the target location unreliable. In reality, the memory controller is free to combine and coalesce writes and there is no way to disable that, so it would take much more than 0.25ns per write.

Comment: @HadiBrais: Interesting, I didn't realize DRAM write endurance was that low.  But the memory clock is well under 4GHz, and a DDR burst transfer will always take multiple cycles to set up.  So probably more like 1 year to wear out a cache line even if you could get the memory controller to do back-to-back writes to the same line.  (`clflush` might actually have the edge over `movnt` there, because for `clflush` to work correctly for NVDIMM storage the data does need to actually go out over the memory bus.  But unlike `clflushopt`, the strongly-ordered semantics will reduce throughput.)

Comment: The write endurance of 6T SRAM, which is usually used for buffers, registers, and caches, is 10^16 as well.

Comment: @HadiBrais: something doesn't add up for those numbers, then.  CPUs can operate at 3 or 4GHz sustained load for multiple years without failing, running workloads that send data through the buffers between pipeline stages every clock cycles.  Unless everything uses extensive ECC to compensate for gates dying all over the place (which I don't think is the case in latches between pipeline stages), real life just doesn't reflect an SRAM endurance of ~10^16 writes.  I'd maybe believe 1 temporary error per 10^16 writes, getting the wrong data for *that* write, but not permanent failure like Flash.

Comment: All papers that I've seen say that SRAM write endurance is about 10^16, although some of them say it's unlimited. But this is just not true. No memory technology has unlimited endurance and it gets worse with smaller node sizes. Read the first paragraph of the first section of [this](https://seal.ece.ucsb.edu/sites/seal.ece.ucsb.edu/files/publications/08008805.pdf) paper. Real processors must be equipped with mechanisms to handle write errors, soft errors, and hard errors. These include duplication, ECC, and parity. Also, Intel's machine check architecture...

Comment: ...allows the OS to be informed of hardware errors that were automatically corrected or uncorrected. In the latter the case, the OS gets the chance of correcting them if possible. Both Linux and Windows use Intel MCA. Pretty much all register files and caches and intensively used buffers need to be design to operate for several years without crashing the system due to hardware errors.